# Equivalents to MSVC's _countof in other compilers?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, macros, clang

Are there any builtin equivalents to [`_countof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773(v=VS.100).aspx) provided by other compilers, in particular GCC and Clang? Are there any non-macro forms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not aware of one for GCC, but Linux uses [GCC's `__builtin_types_compatible_p` builtin](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) to make their `ARRAY_SIZE()` macro safer (it'll cause a build break if applied to a pointer):

```
/* &a[0] degrades to a pointer: a different type from an array */
#define __must_be_array(a) \
 BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(&a[0])))

#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]) + __must_be_array(arr))
```

Note: I think the `BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO()` macro has a misleading name (it causes a build failure if the expression is *not* zero and returns `0` otherwise):

```
/* Force a compilation error if condition is true, but also produce a
   result (of value 0 and type size_t), so the expression can be used
   e.g. in a structure initializer (or where-ever else comma expressions
   aren't permitted). */
#define BUILD_BUG_ON_ZERO(e) (sizeof(struct { int:-!!(e); }))
```

I think the naming for this macro comes from looking at it in two parts:  `BUILD_BUG_ON` is what the macro does when the expression is true, and `ZERO` is the value 'returned' by the macro (if there's not a build break).

Answer (score 25):

Using C++11, the non-macro form is:

```
char arrname[5];
size_t count = std::extent< decltype( arrname ) >::value;
```

And `extent` can be found in the `type_traits` header.

Or if you want it to look a bit nicer, wrap it in this:

```
template < typename T, size_t N >
size_t countof( T ( & arr )[ N ] )
{
    return std::extent< T[ N ] >::value;
}
```

And then it becomes:

```
char arrname[5];
size_t count = countof( arrname );

char arrtwo[5][6];
size_t count_fst_dim = countof( arrtwo );    // 5
size_t count_snd_dim = countof( arrtwo[0] ); // 6
```

**Edit:** I just noticed the "C" flag rather than "C++". So if you're here for C, please kindly ignore this post. Thanks.

Comment: One difference: at least on MSVC, std::extent< decltype( "Character Literal" ) >::value returns 0, while _countof returns the appropriate count.

Comment: Also tested it on GCC and that too, returns 0.

Comment: You have to make your countof function constexpr, otherwise it won't work. Also, it is simpler to "return N;" instead of "std::extent< T[ N ] >::value;".

Comment: That's pretty - I use this often enough that a `countof` really should just be part of std library. @Ash What version? MSVC 2013 returns 6 for countof("Hello") rather than 0.

Comment: curious if 'return N' is a simpler way of implementing template countof()

Answer (score 13):

Update: C++ 17 support [`std::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) (defined in header `<iterator>`)

You can use [`boost::size()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/concept_implementation/semantics/functions.html) instead:

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>

int my_array[10];
boost::size(my_array);
```

Comment: I just love it when people offer boost solutions for even the most trivial one-liner questions totally disregarding that if someone is not already using boost (and there are perfectly valid reasons for not using it), they are supposed to pull in 300+ MB library just for that one thing.

Comment: Only issue is that std::size returns size_t which may need casting when callee has a different prototype (e.g. in Win32 buffer sizes are often defined as int).

Answer (score 8):

This?

`#define _countof(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(*(a)))`

Comment: that would be unsafe when a is a pointer (vs. array). the macro _countof is safe.

Comment: @Uri only in C++. "In C, _countof will produce erroneous results if array is a pointer." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms175773(v=vs.100)