# Array size metafunction - is it in boost somewhere?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, boost, sizeof

I found the following template on a [blog](http://heifner.blogspot.com/2008/04/c-array-size-determination-part-2.html):

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct array_info<T[N]>
{
    typedef T type;
    enum { size = N };
};
```

It is an elegant alternative to `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])`.

A commonly-used construct for getting the size of an array should surely be somewhere in a library.  I'm not aware of one.  Can anyone tell me this functionality is in the standard libraries somewhere and/or in Boost?  Preferably in an easy-to-use and lightweight form.

Comment: There is the standard function `_countof` (you need its template version), but I cannot find the appropriate header at the moment.

Comment: @Vlad `_countof` is nonstandard, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415530/equivalents-to-msvcs-countof-in-other-compilers

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I eventually found the answer myself - `boost::size()`:

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>

int array[10];
boost::size(array); // returns 10
```

Although, these days you should probably use `std::size()` instead (since C++17)

Answer (score 4):

In the new C++ standard, std::array from the  header has the method size(), which returns a constexpr and is therefore available at compile time.

You should be able to to something like

```
std::array< YourType, N > arr;
constexpr auto totalSize = arr.size() * sizeof( std::array< YourType, N >::value_type );
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: +1 Indeed: If you want an solution in the "spirit of C++", use `std::array`.

Comment: Did you mean `std::array<int, 5> arr; constexpr auto sizeInBytes = sizeof(arr); // 20` ?

Answer (score 3):

C++ 17 support [`std::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) (defined in header `<iterator>`)

```
#include <iterator>

int my_array[10];
std::size(my_array);

std::vector<int> my_vector(10);
std::size(my_vector);
```

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would also recommend `std::array` or `boost::array` if possible.  That said, you can also use [boost::extent](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/extent.html) to obtain the array sizes, and [boost::remove_all_extents](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/remove_all_extents.html) to obtain the actual type.

In c++11, the type traits are also available in the standard library.

Edit: If your looking for a function that operates on variables, instead of types, try the following

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t array_count(const T(&) [N]) { return N; }
```

See an example of use at http://ideone.com/IOdfp

Comment: `boost::extent` seems to work on types, not objects.  I need something that works on an array object, e.g. `v` in `char *v[] = {/*...*/}`

Answer (score -1):

You need perhaps the macro `_countof`. According to http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/54241/, it's #defined in `<cstdio>`. But I am not sure if it's available outside Visual C++.

Anyway, it's not complicated to create a header file and put your definition there.

---

Update:
`_countof` is Microsoft-specific, but there is a discussion about other compilers here: [Equivalents to MSVC's _countof in other compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415530/equivalents-to-msvcs-countof-in-other-compilers)