# How to get an array's size?

Tags: c++, c++11

There is an `array` :

```
...
int score[3];
...
score[0] = 6;
score[1] = 4;
score[2] = 7;
```

How to get the array's number of elements ? ( here it is obvious but I want to ask a question in general )

Comment: Please make a minimal research before posting a question, or at least demonstrate some efforts.

Comment: In most cases as soon as you pass the array to a function as an argument the size information is lost. Why you want to use arrays in the first place? C++ arrays is low-level mechanism best suited for libraries. The C++ equivalent of arrays from other languages is `std::vector`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the length of an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108313/how-do-i-find-the-length-of-an-array)

Answer (score 11):

Several ways:

- `std::distance(std::begin(score), std::end(score))`
- `std::extent<decltype(score)>::value`
- [C++17](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/96f4771556de2cc0c5c533eca6515f9faa2ecaa3) ([N4280](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4280.pdf)): `std::size(score)`

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19258233/596781).

Comment: great idea to include future functions c++17. this makes this answer still valid in 6 Years

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is a `sizeof(score) / sizeof(score[0])`. The advantage of this method is understanding of how array works. And it may be the fastest one too, since `sizeof` works at compile time and whole expression could be optimized by compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a macro for that.

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr))
```

You should make yourself familiar with containers (like `std::vector`) which C++ offers. Many of them have methods that can give you actual count of elements stored (`size()` or `length()`).

Regarding C-style arrays, in scenarios where they are passed to function as argument, their size is not known, because an array is just a const pointer.

Comment: That's somewhat dangerous since it will accept a pointer (or any other type with a unary `*` operator), and give surprising results. C++ has safer options.

Comment: Agreed, but that was the first thing that came to my mind for C-style arrays.

Comment: Even then, a function template is safer. `template <typename T, size_t N> size_t size(T(&)[N]) {return N;}` will work for an array, but will give an error rather than a weird result for a pointer.