# C++ - GetLength() method to get length of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm still learning C++. Currently I'm learning arrays and want to get length of an array. I know to get length of an array I have to type:

```
int length = (sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array));
```

It works very well. But, when I make a method to get length that I named as getLength() it doesn't work. Here my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

int getLength(int arg[]){
    return(sizeof(arg)/sizeof(*arg));
}

int main(){
    //array length
    cout << "Displaying array length" << endl;
    cout << getLength(array) << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

That should returns 5, but it returned 1. If I use previous way, it returns 5, even they have same code.

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c "5.3 Pitfall" in particular.

Comment: The answer to *all* your "how to use arrays in C++" is **don't**. Really. Use std::vector.

Comment: One way is to do it like [std::end does it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33496357/1708801) using a template non-type parameter to deduce the array size.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: That's not beginner-level C++, and besides a beginner should learn to use `std::end(arr) - std::begin(arr)`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/26947706/15416

Answer (score 1):

It's because `array` has *decayed* to a pointer type when it's passed to `getLength`.

So in that function, `sizeof` cannot be used to retrieve the total size of the array; it merely evaluates to the size of a pointer to the first element.

The normal thing to do in this instance is pass the size value in to `getLength` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you pass the array to a function, the array decays to a pointer. So `sizeof(arg)` will return the size of the pointer on your architecture. If you need the size you will need to pass an extra parameter to the function.
Check: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: so I can't use a function to get length. Thank you for your explanation :). I'll continue my study.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function with an array, the array decays to the pointer to the first element. The array syntax is quite misleading. The two functions below are equivalent:

```
void func1(int* p) { /* do something */ }
void func2(int p[]) { /* do something */ }
```

See [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying#1461449) for details.

What you can do is to delve into templates. Here's a function that does work:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t array_length(T (&arr)[N])
{
  return N;
}
```

The template captures an array (`arr`) by reference, and the size (`N`) is known by the template matching. Your `main()` example would work with it.

With that said, though, I think you'll be far far better off using `std::vector<>` or `std::array<>` instead. With those, the size is trivially accessible and you get other pleasant properties, not least that they do not decay to pointers.