# C-Preprocessor: Calculate number of elements from an array of structures

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Let's say, I have in a C application a structure:

```
typedef struct {
    int aParameter;
    int anotherParameter;
} Structure_t;
```

and an array of `Structure_t` elements:

```
const Structure_t arrayOfStructres[] = {
    {
        .aParameter = 1,
        .anotherParameter = 2
    },
    {
        .aParameter = 3,
        .anotherParameter = 4
    },
};
```

The `arrayOfStructures` is constant, so no changes during runtime. This means, that theoretically the number of elements in the array is known during compilation time. I know I could calculate the number of elements with

```
sizeof(arrayOfStructures) / sizeof(arrayOfStructes[0]);
```

during runtime, but how to get the number of elements during compilation time with the preprocessor? As the number of elements may be much more than just the two in the example, counting every element when some are added or removed is not very fast and also error prone.

Comment: sizeof runs at compile time

Comment: @stackptr, except for VLA's

Comment: Maybe see [equivalents-to-msvcs-countof-in-other-compilers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415530)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know I could calculate the number of elements with `sizeof(arrayOfStructures)/sizeof(arrayOfStructes[0]);` during runtime

No, that calculation is done at compile-time, so it is what you need.

The only calculation of `sizeof` that is done in run-time is the special case of VLAs, which doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 2):

The `const` qualifier has nothing to do with the number of elements in given array. The arrays in C are of fixed size (well, with notable exception to flexible array member, but it is diffrent thing), with no possibility of extending their elements at runtime.

The `sizeof` operator will (indirectly) give you the number of elements at compile-time. The only exception is with VLA (variable length) arrays, for which sizeof is calculated are runtime, but even with them, you cannot add more elements after declaration (because of that "variable length" is somewhat unfortunate name).

Comment: To be pedantic: `sizeof` returns number of bytes. `sizeof(array)/sizeof(type_of_element)` returns number of elements. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use _countof Macro which operates at compile time, for more information take a look at [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773(v=VS.90).aspx)